# Convert Persian digits to English numbers

Tags: javascript, converting, integer, i18n

I use the following code to convert `۱۲۳۴۵` to ‍`12345`, effectively transliterating the persian numbers into latin numbers:

```js
String.prototype.toEnglishDigits = function () {
        var num_dic = {
            '۰': '0',
            '۱': '1',
            '۲': '2',
            '۳': '3',
            '۴': '4',
            '۵': '5',
            '۶': '6',
            '۷': '7',
            '۸': '8',
            '۹': '9',
        }

        return parseInt(this.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, function (w) {
            return num_dic[w]
        }));
    }

console.log('۱۲۳۴۵'.toEnglishDigits());
```

Comment: Does javascript have something like python's `str.translate`?

Comment: See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31439604/8583692).

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using a map,
you can get the corresponding digits directly by subtracting the character code of `'۰'`.
That is, since the character code of `'۳'` is 1779
and the character code of `'۰'` is 1776, you can calculate that:

```
'۳'.charCodeAt(0) - '۰'.charCodeAt(0) = 1779 - 1776 = 3
```

Using the above logic, the function can be written shorter:

```
String.prototype.toEnglishDigits = function () {
    var charCodeZero = '۰'.charCodeAt(0);
    return parseInt(this.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, function (w) {
        return w.charCodeAt(0) - charCodeZero;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Of course this assumes that the codes for the characters for both roman and persian numerals are sequential. Though this is a logical and desirable feature of an encoding, it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 9):

**Patching core prototypes** like `String` to add non-standard functionality is considered bad software engineering practice, especially in a language where code from various libraries may need to coexist on the same webpage.  I'd just define a regular function.

There's nothing "English" about the output.  The result is a `Number`.  It's not even in base 10.  Really, this is an enhancement to `parseInt()`, and should be named accordingly.

Interestingly, the [inverse operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) is built-in to many browsers (notably not WebKit):

```
(12345).toLocaleString('fa')      # => "۱۲۳۴۵"
```

What you are trying to do, though, has [no built-in browser support](//stackoverflow.com/q/25645163/1157100).  However, note that the problem is not unique to Persian numerals — [many other languages in that part of the world have positional base-10 numeral systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit#Numerals_in_most_popular_systems).  Therefore, I suggest a **generalization**:

```
var PERSIAN_NUMERALS = '۰'.charCodeAt(0);

function numeralParseInt(zero, str) {
    var digits = new Array(str.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        digits[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (zero <= digits[i] && digits[i] < zero + 10) {
            digits[i] -= zero - 48;     // '0' = ASCII 48
        }
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, digits);
}

function persianParseInt(str) {
    return numeralParseInt(PERSIAN_NUMERALS, str);
}
```